# How do you add Ribbons and User Definable functions into Excel using Office 365 Add-ins (formerly Apps for Office) like you can in Office VSTO?

Tags: javascript, vsto, office365api, office-js

Ribbons and User Definable functions are available in VSTO programmatically are they available in Apps for Office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called Addin Commands and are currently in preview for for Word 2016, Excel 2016 and Excel Online. (Add-in commands were made available for Outlook earlier this year).

https://dev.office.com/blogs/Introducing-Office-2016-Add-in-commands-Preview-for-Word-and-Excel

Comment: Thanks Maarten do you know if User Definable Functions are available also?

Comment: No, User Defined Functions is something that we're aware of the interest for, but is not something that is currently available. ~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: Thanks  Michael Zlatkovsky